# Flutter Linux build error X window system error

Tags: linux, flutter, build, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to code in flutter for Linux platform and flutter depend on https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/

I have updated my system to (Elementary os) and after updating and install builds tools for flutter for Linux build to get this error

when run `flutter run -d linux i` get that:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
(store_items:6176): Gdk-ERROR **: 10:22:28.017: The program 'store_items' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadFBConfig'.
  (Details: serial 244 error_code 167 request_code 152 (GLX) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.
Error launching application on Linux.
Exited (sigterm)
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on elementary OS 6 Odin 5.11.0-37-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

`flutter doctor -v` output:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on elementary OS 6 Odin 5.11.0-37-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at /home/rasol/DevTools/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (4 days ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/rasol/DevTools/Android
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/rasol/DevTools/android
    • Java binary at: /home/rasol/Apps/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/rasol/Apps/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 59.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 203.8292
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • elementary OS 6 Odin 5.11.0-37-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.71

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Judging by all the check marks and what the messages say, these aren't error messages. They are just saying that everything worked. In fact, the second message even says "No issues found!" I'm glad to say that there is nothing wrong here; you can go right ahead coding!

Comment: This ideed seems OK. Did you post the right thing? I see no error message (I suspect you forgot to paste it after the second paragraph).

Comment: Did something not work when running, or were these messages the only problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have added the error code under ''when run flutter run -d linux i get that:"
foruth line @SylvesterKruin